# Vagrant with Docker Provider fails with rsync over ssh

Tags: ssh, docker, vagrant, rsync, boot2docker

I have problems to run Vagrant with Docker. The issue is the rsync of the shared folders.

```
WDFM32388067A:vagranttest d022051$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'docker' provider...
==> default: Docker host is required. One will be created if necessary...
    default: Vagrant will now create or start a local VM to act as the Docker
    default: host. You'll see the output of the `vagrant up` for this VM below.
    default:  
    default: Importing base box 'hashicorp/boot2docker'...
    default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
    default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/boot2docker' is up to date...
    default: Setting the name of the VM: docker-host_default_1438155600426_39792
    default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
    default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 2375 => 2375 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
    default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
    default: Booting VM...
    default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: docker
    default: SSH auth method: password
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Syncing folders to the host VM...
    default: Installing rsync to the VM...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

rsync --help

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

sh: rsync: not found

    default: The previous process exited with exit code 1.
    default: The previous process exited with exit code 1.
```

From the error message it is not clear whether ssh or rsync is the issue. Maybe it is because ssh is timing out. I tried all possible ssh options but nothing did work out. For example I set an config.ssh.private_key_path but still the error message was exactly the same. Has anybody had similar issues?

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 2):

I was also stuck with hashicorp/boot2docker.  Moving to mitchell/boot2docker didn't help, either, but I found that

https://vagrantcloud.com/dduportal/boxes/boot2docker

works well (and is more up-to-date).

Comment: nope, rsync is installed. I'm on MacOS. rsync is under /opt/local/bin and is in the path.

Comment: I also created a symlink to /bin. Didn't change anything.

Comment: Ah, my bad, it looks like rsync is not found on the guest:     
`default: Installing rsync to the VM...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!`

Comment: How did you specify a different boot2docker image? I'm using docker as provider.

Comment: Nvm, figured it out, you need an additional `Vagrantfile` that contains something similar to: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/plugins/providers/docker/hostmachine/Vagrantfile with the image you like. Finally, you just need to include this line on your main `Vagrantfile`: `d.vagrant_vagrantfile = "Vagrantfile-boot2docker"`

Comment: @gregor did you find a solution for this? I have the same issue with the same docker image.